# Rewrite root to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get www.example.com to show the content at www.example.com/content/portal/

I'm not wanting a simple redirect, the url should show www.example.com. I've tried a number of the rewrite codes from this site but they all just redirect the page.

BTW I do redirect non-www urls to www.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your .htaccess file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteRule ^$ content/portal/ [L]
```